# Please don't redirect your anime ID requests to Anime.SE − we don't want them

Tags: discussion, identify

I'm not sure if everybody knows this already, but after seeing a comment left by a user with a few thousand rep under a bad anime ID here to try Anime.SE, I thought it's worth mentioning:

[Anime.SE has decided that we don't accept anime or manga identification requests.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions)

So, please, don't recommend the OP to ask on Anime.SE coz it will only get deleted.

Users who have enough rep to post in chat may ask in [our main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-), but common sense of asking ID request still applies − if you don't remember anything, or it's too vague, nobody will be able to help you there either.

Comment: Anime question are on topic here ( either ID or non ID), I can't see any use of such comments so I will advice to flag those instantly and I know that ID are off topic there.